# Cannot access drag adorner template

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, datatemplate, adorner

I've used the sample code provided by Bea Stollnitz (http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=53), in order to enable drag and drop in my application, and drag adorner, etc.

Everything works fine, my drag adorner is well displayed, I have all the behavior I want.

But (yes there is always a but), I cannot access the DataTemplate of the Drag Adorner, in order to display different data depending on the dragged data.

I have simplified the code, but the basics are still there.

This is the DataTemplate of my DragAdorner

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DragAndDropTemplate" DataType="{x:Type MyType}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid Opacity="0.5">
                <Border x:Name="HeaderBorder" CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5,2,5,2">
                   <Border x:Name="InsideBorder" CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="1">
                      <TextBlock x:Name="number" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
                   </Border>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
            <Border Width="17" Height="17" BorderBrush="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" CornerRadius="1" x:Name="numberContainer" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <TextBlock x:Name="number" Text="80" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

This is the code that create the Adorner :

```
if (this.draggedAdorner == null)
        {
            var adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(source);
            this.draggedAdorner = new DraggedAdorner(draggedData, dataTemplate, source, adornerLayer);
        }
```

And this is the code that init an adorner

```
public DraggedAdorner(List dragDropData, DataTemplate dragDropTemplate, FrameworkElement adornedElement, AdornerLayer adornerLayer)
        : base(adornedElement)
    {
        this.adornerLayer = adornerLayer;
        this.contentPresenter = new ContentPresenter();

        this.contentPresenter.Content = dragDropData[0];

        this.contentPresenter.ContentTemplate = dragDropTemplate;
        this.adornerLayer.Add(this);
    }
```

The draggedData, will be a list of MyType, I get the first item as the content of the ContentPresenter of my DraggedAdorner, so the DataTemplate can apply.

The problem is, I want to access the numberContainer and number control of the DataTemplate, in order to display the number of dragged object, in the adorner. But I cannot manage to access it, whatever I try, It ends with the "This operation is valid only on elements that have this template applied." message.

I have tought I could do something like this :

```
this.contentPresenter.ContentTemplate.FindName("number", this.contentPresenter);
```

Since the DataTemplate should apply to the ContentPresenter, but nope...
For information the adornedElement is the ListViewItem from which the drag occurs.

If you have any idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I have found how to achieve what I wanted.

I don't know why it didn't comes to mind earlier, and why I didn't found anything about this before.

I have just added a single line before trying to access the template :

```
this.UpdateLayout()
```

Looks like it forces the ContentPresenter and DataTemplate object to be update and "re-rederend" so the ContentPresenter is really templated by my DataTemplate.